# System.Web.HttpException. in asp.net (failed to load view state ) occurs only during postback request

Tags: asp.net

In a page_load method, I am trying to a panel inside another panel. During GET() request its working fine. But while post back request its giving System.Web.HttpException. The exception occurs only during update button click event, not others.

The error description is as - 
{"Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request."}

Unable to see initial request hierarchy of adding panels.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I would say make sure you only Databind when Page.IsPostBack is false. Usually you see that error when you Databind on postback. See here for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/10/25/why-we-get-the-exception-failed-to-load-viewstate.aspx

Comment: If you are dynamically adding any controls, the error usually indicates that the naming is not the same on each and every creation step. You also need to create the controls in the same exact order and do both at the appropriate time, which is before the second postback event occurs, usually in the OnLoad event of the page/control at the very latest.